# Generate Stubs for WSDL Having Header using Apache CXF

Tags: java, soap, cxf, soapui

Hi I am trying to generate WSDL Stubs using apache CXF plugin. Stubs are getting generated. But I have header also in my WSDL and my main consumer class of stubs has no place to send header with request.

My working plugin for stubs is :

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.18</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/new.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/Bindings.xml</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Do i need to anything else to generate headers also in plugin?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your wsdl?